# Azure Datafactory: Dataflow can't access database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, azure-data-factory

I've been building a nice ETL solution with Data Factory. We're bound to go to the production stage and now security becomes a real concern. Somehow I can't seem to get this right....

I've set up a CosmosDB and SQL Server/DB in Azure. I've added those to a virtual network and disallowed any connections outside of that network.
In DataFactory I've set up an Integration Runtime with Virtual network configuration.
I've added a Managed Private Endpoint in DataFactory, connected to the SQL server.
I've set up a Linked Service to the SQL server using that endpoint.
When I set up a Dataset using that Linked Service it works as expected. I can test the connection succesfully, select a table and retrieve it's schema.

However.....
I've set up a dataflow that retrieves data from the CosmosDB, does all kinds of magic with it and writes it to a sink using the dataset defined above. When I try to test the connection on this sink, it fails stating that it can't access the SQL database.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the difference between running a pipeline (using the IR) and running a dataflow (whatever that uses?). I can't, however, find what runs that dataflow and how to make sure that "thing" can access the SQL server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a SQL Server on a VM, or is it Azure SQL DB? Data flows cannot connect to SQL Server today, only to Azure SQL DB/SQL MI.

Comment: It's an Azure SQL DB

Comment: @Croga did you get any error message?

Comment: The specific error message I get when trying to access the SQL server from any data flow is:
at Source 'DataSQLInvoiceView': java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot connect to SQL database: 'jdbc:sqlserver://dbdevsocdashboard.database.windows.net;database={<redacted>}', 'User: <redacted>'. Please check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

(redacted the sensitive information :-))

Comment: Is the SQL DB a public or private endpoint? If it's behind a firewall, you'll to set "allow azure services" exception in your SQL DB.

Comment: @Mark; The SQL DB is in a virtual network with a private endpoint. The Datafactory has a private endpoint linking it to the SQL DB. I was under the impression that that was the only thing needed and that "Allow azure services" would open up the SQL DB to *all* Azure services, not just my datafactory.

Comment: Also; to clarify: I have a linked service to the SQL DB and a test connection is succesful. I have a dataset using that linked service and a test connection there is succesful. I have a pipeline that uses that dataset and a debug run of that is succesful. As soon as I use the dataset in a dataflow, however, it fails.

Comment: Are you using MSI auth? If that still doesn't work, then enable the managed vnet option on the Azure IR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After activating, then deactivating, the "Deny public network access" option on the SQL Server "Firewalls and Virtual Networks" setting page, everything started working as expected.

Apparently "Have you tried turning it off an on again" is still the solution to some issues....